# How to move button to the right by using bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have tried `float right`, `pull-right`even `ml`. The button still sitting there!! Why?

[image]

```
    <main class="container bg-primary">
        <div class="row g-2"> 
            <div class="col-10 bg-danger">
                <input class="w-100" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 bg-danger">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Warning</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to align button on the right inside col-2 it's enough to add text-right class (if you use bootstrap 5 use text-end):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main class="container bg-primary">
        <div class="row g-2"> 
            <div class="col-10 bg-danger">
               <input class="w-100" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 bg-danger text-end">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Warning</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean, I tried ```text-right```, it is not working

Comment: I use this bootstrap example link, ```<link href="../assets/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">```

Comment: I just tried it and for me it's working. Did you put text-right in col-2? <div class="col-2 bg-danger text-right">. If you put it inside button it will not work

Comment: I solved it, bootstrap 5 uses ```text-end``` instead of ```text-right```. Thanks

Comment: Just edited my answer :)